# Windows And Application Settings Disabled By Administrator/Organizer on a PERSONAL computer

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-10, virus

I am not able to change some of the settings because they are enforced by my Administrator/organizer, but the catch is that my laptop is a private/personal computer that I purchased myself and is not connected to my school/work networks in anyways.

Is this a virus/adware or something of that form?

I have "BitDefender Total Security 2016" purchased and running on my computer with all the protection settings on, on the highest level of protection except for "Ransomware Protection". It went away for a day after I upgraded to Windows 10, but then it came back.

Here are these settings I cannot tweak:

**Search Engine Setting in Google Chrome**

[image]

And when I search something up this website comes up (which is set as my search engine):
**The Website That Is Set As My Search Engine**

[image]

And here is the Windows settings that I can't tweak:

**Show App Notifications In Windows Settings**

[image]

and **Another One**:

[image]

And as I said before my computer is

**Protected By BitDefender**

[image]

I have 3 questions:
1.What could have set my default search engine to whatever it is now?
2.Why can I not change it?
3.How can I change it?

For more needed details reply to this post. Thank you!

Comment: Please upload your screenshots to imgur your google drive does not work for me.  If you post just the urls somebody will inline for you.

Comment: Not to mention I'm the only user on this computer and so there is only my user account on the computer and I have the Administrative Privileges.

Comment: **Is this a virus?** - It is not a virus.  Even with the screenshots, I have doubts, your question would be clear.

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? Please don't do that. You already asked [Unable to change some settings in Windows 10 and in Google Chrome](http://superuser.com/q/1038525)

Comment: If you enable the built-in Administrator account.  Can you change these settings?

Comment: I did not know it was posted! I'll delete the other one now.

Comment: I already uploaded them but it doesnt let me share more than two, because it shares them as links. I can see them in the post can't you?

Comment: @Matin - Whatever you shared originally were not links in either questions.

Comment: Ok, now back to the topic what are you saying isn't clear?

Comment: By virus I ment adware or stuff like that because I only set my search engine to Google and nothing else. And no one else has access to my computer, so my I have 3 questions. 1.What could have set my default search engine to whatever it is now? 2.Why can I not change it? 3.How can I change it?